# How could "cryonics" be "just a fad"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, cryogenics

In "The Neutral Zone", the Enterprise happens upon a number of 20th century individuals who have been frozen as sent drifting in space to be hopefully found later and healed.   They are easily ... unfrozen and healed.

But Data states:

> Actually the process of cryonics
>   was never more than a fad, and
>   did not continue much beyond the
>   mid-twenty-first century.

How is it supposed to be plausible that there existed the technology to freeze people in the 20th and 21th centuries and the technology to revive them in the 24th century, but no one ever uses it?   There ought to have been many cases where it would have been useful to freeze people to be thawed later.   And are we to believe there were no people in the 22nd century who wanted to "live forever" and would have taken the same route after reliable power and space travel were commonplace?

Comment: He's probably just talking about lowering the individual's temperature. There might be other ways to stop a person's metabolism that are less risky.

Comment: @DavidS and PointlessSpike:   You're missing the point that even if that have some similar to "cryonics" but not cryonics, we don't see them use it and we don't see any other individuals showing up.

Comment: I suppose that cryonics may have been replaced with stasis technology. Does anyone have a timeline of when this was invented?

Comment: Fair point, deleted.

Comment: There is also a relatively low-tech alternative, once impulse drive is commonplace: take an old ship, accelerate to as near C as is possible without using warp drive (possibly perpendicular to the galactic plane to avoid traffic), and let the universe go by. This would, with a good enough subspace receiver and computer, also have the advantage of letting the temporal refugee choose his moment of return on the fly. On the other hand, I can think of at least 2 occasions where this might have made sense in-universe but they ignored it.

Comment: For the record, I'm fairly sure that Data is referring to fad of freezing oneself (after death) rather than the more mundane explanation that cryogenics has been supplanted by stasis technology.

Comment: Presumably because warp drive meant that freezing people to transport them long distances was no longer necessary.

Answer (score 11):

As stated by Dima in their answer, there may have been a lengthy amount of time between the development of effective cryonics and the ability to revive people without killing them. Secondly, and possibly more likely, it simply became less useful. Medicine has advanced substantially since the 20th and 21st century and not only are there likely fewer diseases to protect against, but there are probably also better methods to preserve people for future medical development.

More likely, in my opinion, is that the practice declined because, by the time they started finding ways to cure these diseases, and to safely revive people, they also started realizing just how expensive it all was. What purpose do people in cryostorage serve? If they're revived a hundred years, or even a smaller amount of time such as fifty years, they're going to be tremendously out-of-touch with society. Their prior skillset is likely to be obsolete. Their social values will likely include all sorts of horrible things like casual racism or a desire to rebel against a despotic empire such as the Federation. You'd need to spend considerable resources to bring them up to even a functioning level, and the odds are that they'd feel out of touch for the rest of their life. In short, most people probably started to realize that the odds were that either they'd never be revived or they'd be miserable once revived.

Comment: This really ignores the fact that (a) some people are immensely valuable and (b) most people value their own lives for out of proportion to everyone else, so the wealthy and powerful, at least, will take advantage of whatever exists regardless of logic or cost.   Case in point:  The state of the medical system in the US.

Comment: {nods} But, in the end, how do they get someone to thaw them out?

Comment: No one is that valuable. Society has gone on without the "valuable" existing longer than anyone else for all of our history. We've done just fine without them.

Comment: "they also started realizing just how expensive it all was" -- except that in Roddenberry's future utopia, one of the big points was that money had been eliminated, and considerations of expense/value didn't seem to figure into considerations of whether to undertake a given project (for example, one of the projects they were working on back home on Earth in the TNG episode "Family" was the [New Atlantis Project](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/New_Atlantis_Project), whose goal was to create an entire new continent in the Atlantic Ocean).

Comment: @Hypnosifl: 
{nods} But expense is not necessarily monetary. Especially in a post-scarcity society, human time is a valuable asset.

Comment: True, but with such a large, well-educated population, who [according to Picard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNtz-sOLdqU) were commonly motivated by the desire "work to better ourselves", you'd think there would be quite a lot of people interested in acts of service to others who might need it, especially interesting and intellectually challenging service. So I'd think there'd be plenty of qualified volunteers eager for the opportunity to introduce a centuries-old individual to their new world and help them to acclimatize, teach them whatever new knowledge they wanted to pick up, etc.

Answer (score 6):

They have ["Stasis Fields"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stasis) in the 24th century.  I don't recall hearing a date associated with their invention, but it's possible that by the time the technology existed to "unfreeze" someone and fix them, statis fields had also been invented, rendering the cryogenic method as obsolete.

Comment: Good point, and we can combine this with Dima's suggestion by imagining that even if the invention of stasis fields was relatively recent, the ability to revive cryogenically frozen people was even more recent, so before that cryogenics could have died out because there was no way of knowing if it would work, and after that people would just use stasis fields rather than cryogenics in most cases (though it seems [cryostasis](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cryostasis) was still used in some circumstances, perhaps a combo. of the two technologies).

Comment: Although the first part is true, I'm not certain that the *means* are what's faddy, I think it's the whole "freezing yourself" thing that's seen as passé

Answer (score 5):

Cryogenics will fade out as a fad as soon as people realize that *no one is ever going to revive these 'corpsicles'*.  The progress of technology is irrelevant - the problem is that the psychology is all wrong: whoever has to decide whether or not to revive someone almost certainly has no incentive to decide 'yes'.

- If civilization is going well, we surely have enough (or too many) people alive already; if not so well, surely we have more pressing things to do than try to reanimate the dead *[and let's be clear about this - they ARE dead]*.
- We already have cheaper (and more fun!) ways to bring people into this world.
- Whatever you know is hopelessly out of date.  And if we're going to try to train someone to be a productive member of this society, surely it will be easier and more reliable to work with someone who doesn't have any crap already in their head (i.e a baby).
- Oh, you say you set up some legal arrangement for yourself, to pay for your upkeep and eventual revival, and leave you rich when you wake up?  Well sorry, but while you were 'sleeping' the politicians decided that you were physically dead, hence legally dead, and confiscated all the money.  You had no legal standing to complain because, well, you're dead.
- You expect us to do WHAT?  Grow a fully adult copy of you, then expect it to agree to die just so we can put YOUR head on ITS body??  Jeez, what were you smoking, man!?
- You think we'll want to revive you to fill in gaps in our knowledge of your times?  Didn't you ever notice just how many records got put onto the Internet?  Hell, consider Wikipedia all by itself!
- Sure we'll revive them!  Congress just passed The Second Freezer Bill - more spare parts for everybody!  *[thanks for that image, Larry Niven!]*
- You think you could be the perfect infiltration agent for our rebellion against Our Great Leader, because you have no records on file?  PUH-LEEZ - just TRY to get past a DNA test, or even a retinal scan!  *[thanks for that image, Woody Allen!].*

Comment: It could be a handy thing to wake up craftsman and specialists as the need arose. Birthday party clowns. Baristas. Canadian talk show hosts. You know. For the critical stuff.

Comment: Can't forget equipment failure. There was a conversation in the episode itself about some facilities experiencing brown-outs and losing customercicles.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than the cryonics actually falling out of favor in the 21st century, let's consider an alternate theory - **no one really care about living on because life sucked** and when things improved, no one really cared about it anymore because there were bigger things to think about.

In the history of Star Trek there were a couple of cataclysmic events on Earth in the 21st century the effectively changed the course of the planet:

1. [World War III](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/World_War_III)
2. The [Flight of the Phoenix](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Phoenix) and [First Contact](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/First_contact#Human-Vulcan_first_contact)

As we learned in [the First Contact movie](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact), in some of the backstory of [Enterprise](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Enterprise) and the DS9 two part episode [Past](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Past_Tense,_Part_I_(episode)) [Tense](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Past_Tense,_Part_II_(episode)), the early-to-mid 21st century on Earth was not the best place to live.  Why would anyone want to "live forever" (or at least continue to live on)?

By the time things improved after WW3 and First Contact, the pseudo-utopian society of Earth began to evolve.  The ideas of material possession slowly began to fade away and people became less self involved.  As a result, the idea of freezing yourself until a cure could be found for your "incurable disease" because less important.  And when no one care about it, the industry slowly disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the fad did not last because people in 21st or 22nd century had no sure way of knowing that there will be a technology in the 24th century to revive the frozen individuals. Or that the cryogenic equipment would continue functioning for that long.

Comment: Maybe, but in the 24th century, presumably they do know, and it's still not used.

Comment: In the 24th century there are cures for the diseases that were killing the people who had themselves frozen.

Comment: @Dima So there were no more incurable diseases in the 24th century?

Comment: @Turch, cryogenics only makes sense when the person is reasonably young, and could go on to live a full life if cured. I would expect that in the 24th century most diseases that can kill at a young age would be eradicated.

Comment: @Dima Fair enough, from the perspective of the "human diseases" (heart problems, cancer, etc) that makes sense. I was thinking more about the occasional "there's some alien virus that came out of nowhere and will kill everyone", but that's at a massive scale that would present other (logistical, institutional) problems. Individual-based cryogenics only works if there are common diseases that affect a smaller portion of a population. So I agree is what I'm saying.